# Why are all the strings the same

Tags: c, string, random

For test my hashmap on C language I need to generate many *keys* (string). I wrote this code for generate keys. And this code doesn't works.

```
    char* keys [15] = { 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        char key [7] = { 0 };
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
        {
            int rand_char = rand()%26+'A';
            key[j] = (char)rand_char;
        }
        *(keys + i) = key; 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        printf("%s\n", keys[i]);
```

The problem is all keys are the same and I don't know why this happens.
OUPUT:

```
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
```

I tried putting the random result into a variable (int rand_char) and also tried the debug keys during the generation process and saw that all the letters change when new letters are generated, as if all the lines were one string.

```
char* keys [15] = { 0 };

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    char key [7] = { 0 };
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
    {
        int rand_char = rand()%26+'A';
        key[j] = (char)rand_char;
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)
            printf("%s\n", keys[k]); 
    }
    *(keys + i) = key; 
}
```

OUPUT:

```
B
BM
BMQ
BMQB
BMQBH
C
C
CD
CD
CDA
CDA
CDAR
CDAR
CDARZ
CDARZ
O
O
O
OW
OW
OW
OWK
OWK
OWK
OWKK
OWKK
OWKK
OWKKY
OWKKY
OWKKY
H
H
H
H
HI
HI
HI
HI
HID
HID
HID
HID
HIDD
HIDD
HIDD
HIDD
HIDDQ
HIDDQ
HIDDQ
HIDDQ
S
S
S
S
S
SC
SC
SC
SC
SC
SCD
SCD
SCD
SCD
SCD
SCDX
SCDX
SCDX
SCDX
SCDX
SCDXR
SCDXR
SCDXR
SCDXR
SCDXR
J
J
J
J
J
J
JM
JM
JM
JM
JM
JM
JMO
JMO
JMO
JMO
JMO
JMO
JMOW
JMOW
JMOW
JMOW
JMOW
JMOW
JMOWF
JMOWF
JMOWF
JMOWF
JMOWF
JMOWF
R
R
R
R
R
R
R
RX
RX
RX
RX
RX
RX
RX
RXS
RXS
RXS
RXS
RXS
RXS
RXS
RXSJ
RXSJ
RXSJ
RXSJ
RXSJ
RXSJ
RXSJ
RXSJY
RXSJY
RXSJY
RXSJY
RXSJY
RXSJY
RXSJY
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
BL
BL
BL
BL
BL
BL
BL
BL
BLD
BLD
BLD
BLD
BLD
BLD
BLD
BLD
BLDB
BLDB
BLDB
BLDB
BLDB
BLDB
BLDB
BLDB
BLDBE
BLDBE
BLDBE
BLDBE
BLDBE
BLDBE
BLDBE
BLDBE
F
F
F
F
F
F
F
F
F
FS
FS
FS
FS
FS
FS
FS
FS
FS
FSA
FSA
FSA
FSA
FSA
FSA
FSA
FSA
FSA
FSAR
FSAR
FSAR
FSAR
FSAR
FSAR
FSAR
FSAR
FSAR
FSARC
FSARC
FSARC
FSARC
FSARC
FSARC
FSARC
FSARC
FSARC
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
BY
BY
BY
BY
BY
BY
BY
BY
BY
BY
BYN
BYN
BYN
BYN
BYN
BYN
BYN
BYN
BYN
BYN
BYNE
BYNE
BYNE
BYNE
BYNE
BYNE
BYNE
BYNE
BYNE
BYNE
BYNEC
BYNEC
BYNEC
BYNEC
BYNEC
BYNEC
BYNEC
BYNEC
BYNEC
BYNEC
D
D
D
D
D
D
D
D
D
D
D
DY
DY
DY
DY
DY
DY
DY
DY
DY
DY
DY
DYG
DYG
DYG
DYG
DYG
DYG
DYG
DYG
DYG
DYG
DYG
DYGG
DYGG
DYGG
DYGG
DYGG
DYGG
DYGG
DYGG
DYGG
DYGG
DYGG
DYGGX
DYGGX
DYGGX
DYGGX
DYGGX
DYGGX
DYGGX
DYGGX
DYGGX
DYGGX
DYGGX
X
X
X
X
X
X
X
X
X
X
X
X
XP
XP
XP
XP
XP
XP
XP
XP
XP
XP
XP
XP
XPK
XPK
XPK
XPK
XPK
XPK
XPK
XPK
XPK
XPK
XPK
XPK
XPKL
XPKL
XPKL
XPKL
XPKL
XPKL
XPKL
XPKL
XPKL
XPKL
XPKL
XPKL
XPKLO
XPKLO
XPKLO
XPKLO
XPKLO
XPKLO
XPKLO
XPKLO
XPKLO
XPKLO
XPKLO
XPKLO
R
R
R
R
R
R
R
R
R
R
R
R
R
RE
RE
RE
RE
RE
RE
RE
RE
RE
RE
RE
RE
RE
REL
REL
REL
REL
REL
REL
REL
REL
REL
REL
REL
REL
REL
RELL
RELL
RELL
RELL
RELL
RELL
RELL
RELL
RELL
RELL
RELL
RELL
RELL
RELLN
RELLN
RELLN
RELLN
RELLN
RELLN
RELLN
RELLN
RELLN
RELLN
RELLN
RELLN
RELLN
M
M
M
M
M
M
M
M
M
M
M
M
M
M
MP
MP
MP
MP
MP
MP
MP
MP
MP
MP
MP
MP
MP
MP
MPA
MPA
MPA
MPA
MPA
MPA
MPA
MPA
MPA
MPA
MPA
MPA
MPA
MPA
MPAP
MPAP
MPAP
MPAP
MPAP
MPAP
MPAP
MPAP
MPAP
MPAP
MPAP
MPAP
MPAP
MPAP
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
MPAPQ
```

Comment: `char key [7] = { 0 };` will only live as long as its surrounding context, which is the outer for loop. You probably will need a string function like `str(n)dup`.

Comment: Where do you call `srand`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you don't allocate memory for all keys: all `keys[x]` point to `key`.

You can correct this by

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    //char* keys [15] = { 0 }; // only memory for pointers
    char keys [15][7] = { 0 }; // memory for keys

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        //char key [7] = { 0 };
        char *key = keys[i]; // just modify keys[i]
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
        {
            int rand_char = rand()%26+'A';
            key[j] = (char)rand_char;
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        printf("%s\n", keys[i]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First for the explanation:

```
char* keys [15] = { 0 };

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    char key [7] = { 0 };
    *(keys + i) = key; // now keys[i] contains a pointer to the array `key`
}
/* The object with identifier `key`'s lifetime has ended here.
 * If you try to access it via ANY of the pointers stored in `keys`,
 * you invoke undefined behaviour.
 * That means, summarily, that your program is not a valid C program.
 */
```

Instead, you need to allocate enough memory somehow to store the generated strings so that their lifetime extends to whenever and wherever you want to use them.

One way to do so is define `keys` like so, at the appropriate scope:

```
char keys[15][7] = {0};
for (int idx = 0; idx < sizeof keys / sizeof *keys; ++idx) {
  for(int j = 0; j < sizeof *keys / sizeof **keys; ++j) {
    keys[idx][j] = (char) rand() % 26 + 'A';
  }
}

/* Now use `keys`... */
```

Alternatively, you can allocate memory dynamically with `malloc` and friends, if your actual application has more complex requirements than your given example code.